# How to set worker number per node, and executor number per worker in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running Spark on EMR cluster, and I notice the computation resource is not fully used. Right now there is only 1 worker on each node (m3.xlarge), and only 1 executor on each worker.

I checked this Spark doc http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html and there is a configuration `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES` by which I can set the worker number per node, but I can't find the executor number settings.

Maybe for YARN I can set `--num-executors` but I'm not using YARN.

Does any one know this?

Comment: How are you running the spark application??

Comment: What did you specify the slaves configuration?

Comment: Hi @Anil, I don't use the integrated Spark on EMR now, but in the old way: get all the necessary files ready like spark-1.0.1-bin-hadoop1.tgz, and run shell in master and slaves: `${HADOOP_TARGET}/spark/sbin/start-master.sh` and `${HADOOP_TARGET}/spark/sbin/spark-daemon.sh start org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker $(hostname) spark://$MASTER:7077`, many params like `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES ` are set thru environment variables.

Comment: It's running on a standalone EMR cluster, with 1 m3.xlarge master and several m3.xlarge slaves

Comment: seems for early Spark version, in standalone mode only 1 executor per worker is allowed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1706